# how should i make JSONObject and JSONArray from json url or json

Tags: android, json, parsing

My JSON:

```
{
    "response_code": 200,
    "error": false,
    "train_name": "KCG YPR EXP",
    "train_num": "17603",
    "pnr": "1234567890",
    "failure_rate": 19.346153846153847,
    "doj": "20-8-2015",
    "chart_prepared": "Y",
    "class": "SL",
    "total_passengers": 2,
    "train_start_date": {
        "month": 8,
        "year": 2015,
        "day": 20
    },
    "from_station": {
        "code": "KCG",
        "name": "KACHEGUDA"
    },
    "boarding_point": {
        "code": "KCG",
        "name": "KACHEGUDA"
    },
    "to_station": {
        "code": "YPR",
        "name": "YESVANTPUR JN"
    },
    "reservation_upto": {
        "code": "YPR",
        "name": "YESVANTPUR JN"
    },
    "passengers": [
        {
            "no": 1,
            "booking_status": "S7,58,GN",
            "current_status": "S7,58",
            "coach_position": 9
        },
        {
            "no": 2,
            "booking_status": "S7,59,GN",
            "current_status": "S7,59",
            "coach_position": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

What I did so far:

```
if(jsonStr!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("passengers");
                for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject o=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int no= Integer.parseInt(o.optString("no").toString());
                    String booking_status=o.getString("Booking Status");
                    String current_status=o.getString("Current Status");
                    String coach_position=o.getString("Coach Position");

                    JSONObject data=o.getJSONObject("details");
                    String train_name = data.getString("Train Name");
                    int  train_num = Integer.parseInt(data.optString("train number").toString());
                    int pnr = Integer.parseInt(data.optString("pnr").toString());
                    String chart_prepared = data.getString("Chart Prepared");
                    int total_passengers=Integer.parseInt(data.optString("total passengers").toString());

                    JSONObject date=data.getJSONObject("tarin_start_date");
                    int month=Integer.parseInt(data.optString("month").toString());
                    int year=Integer.parseInt(data.optString("year").toString());
                    int day=Integer.parseInt(data.optString("day").toString());


                    JSONObject co=date.getJSONObject("from_station");
                    String code=co.getString("code");
                    String name=co.getString("name");

                    JSONObject co1=co.getJSONObject("boarding_point");
                    String code1=co1.getString("code");
                    String name1=co1.getString("name");

                    JSONObject co2=co1.getJSONObject("to_station");
                    String code2=co2.getString("code");
                    String name2=co2.getString("name");

                    JSONObject co3=co2.getJSONObject("from_station");
                    String code3=co3.getString("code");
                    String name3=co3.getString("name");

                    HashMap<String,String> dtail=new HashMap<>();
                    dtail.put("no", String.valueOf(no));
                    dtail.put("Booking Staus",booking_status);
                    dtail.put("Current Staus",current_status);
                    dtail.put("Coach Positon",coach_position);
                    dtail.put("Train Name",train_name);
                    dtail.put("Train Number", String.valueOf(train_num));
                    dtail.put("pnr", String.valueOf(pnr));
                    dtail.put("chart prepared",chart_prepared);
                    dtail.put("total passengers", String.valueOf(total_passengers));
                    dtail.put("month", String.valueOf(month));
                    dtail.put("year", String.valueOf(year));
                    dtail.put("day", String.valueOf(day));
                    dtail.put("code",code);
                    dtail.put("name",name);
                    dtail.put("code",code1);
                    dtail.put("name",name1);
                    dtail.put("code",code2);
                    dtail.put("name",name2);
                    dtail.put("code",code3);
                    dtail.put("name",name3);

                    dataList.add(dtail);


                }
            }
            catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
return null;
        }
```

Comment: so where is your problem?

Comment: getting a error at run() method array index 0 out of range[0..0]

Comment: fix your code first, you have a lot of different keys, in JSIN you have `total_passengers` but in code you call it as `data.optString("total passengers"`  and so on

Comment: so what sholud i do can u post the code by correcting it please...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: they are using httpClient which have been deprecated already can you correct my code

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :-

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dummy);
 String str = "{\n" +
                "    \"response_code\": 200,\n" +
                "    \"error\": false,\n" +
                "    \"train_name\": \"KCG YPR EXP\",\n" +
                "    \"train_num\": \"17603\",\n" +
                "    \"pnr\": \"1234567890\",\n" +
                "    \"failure_rate\": 19.346153846153847,\n" +
                "    \"doj\": \"20-8-2015\",\n" +
                "    \"chart_prepared\": \"Y\",\n" +
                "    \"class\": \"SL\",\n" +
                "    \"total_passengers\": 2,\n" +
                "    \"train_start_date\": {\n" +
                "        \"month\": 8,\n" +
                "        \"year\": 2015,\n" +
                "        \"day\": 20\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"from_station\": {\n" +
                "        \"code\": \"KCG\",\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"KACHEGUDA\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"boarding_point\": {\n" +
                "        \"code\": \"KCG\",\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"KACHEGUDA\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"to_station\": {\n" +
                "        \"code\": \"YPR\",\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"YESVANTPUR JN\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"reservation_upto\": {\n" +
                "        \"code\": \"YPR\",\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"YESVANTPUR JN\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"passengers\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"no\": 1,\n" +
                "            \"booking_status\": \"S7,58,GN\",\n" +
                "            \"current_status\": \"S7,58\",\n" +
                "            \"coach_position\": 9\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"no\": 2,\n" +
                "            \"booking_status\": \"S7,59,GN\",\n" +
                "            \"current_status\": \"S7,59\",\n" +
                "            \"coach_position\": 9\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";
        parseJson(str);
}


   private void parseJson(String jsonStr) {
    HashMap<String, String> dtail = new HashMap<>();
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            int responseCode = object.getInt("response_code");
            boolean error = object.getBoolean("error");
            String train_name = object.getString("train_name");
            int train_num = object.getInt("train_num");
            int pnr = object.getInt("pnr");
            double failurerate = object.getDouble("failure_rate");
            String dateofJoin = object.getString("doj");
            String chart = object.getString("chart_prepared");
            String Class = object.getString("class");
            int total_passengers = object.getInt("total_passengers");
            JSONObject date = object.getJSONObject("train_start_date");
            int month = date.getInt("month");
            int year = date.getInt("year");
            int day = date.getInt("day");

            JSONObject co = object.getJSONObject("from_station");
            String code = co.getString("code");
            String name = co.getString("name");

            JSONObject co1 = object.getJSONObject("boarding_point");
            String code1 = co1.getString("code");
            String name1 = co1.getString("name");

            JSONObject co2 = object.getJSONObject("to_station");
            String code2 = co2.getString("code");
            String name2 = co2.getString("name");

            JSONObject co3 = object.getJSONObject("from_station");
            String code3 = co3.getString("code");
            String name3 = co3.getString("name");

            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("passengers");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int no = jsonObject.getInt("no");
                String booking_status = jsonObject.getString("booking_status");
                String current_status = jsonObject.getString("current_status");
                int coach_position = jsonObject.getInt("coach_position");
                dtail.put("no", String.valueOf(no));
                dtail.put("booking_status", booking_status);
                dtail.put("current_status", current_status);
                dtail.put("coach_position", String.valueOf(coach_position));
            }
            dtail.put("responseCode", String.valueOf(responseCode));
            dtail.put("error", "" + error);
            dtail.put("Train Name", train_name);
            dtail.put("dateofJoin", dateofJoin);
            dtail.put("chart", chart);
            dtail.put("Class", Class);
            dtail.put("Train Number", String.valueOf(train_num));
            dtail.put("pnr", String.valueOf(pnr));
            dtail.put("FAILURE_RATE", String.valueOf(failurerate));
            dtail.put("total passengers", String.valueOf(total_passengers));
            dtail.put("month", String.valueOf(month));
            dtail.put("year", String.valueOf(year));
            dtail.put("day", String.valueOf(day));
            dtail.put("code", code);
            dtail.put("name", name);
            dtail.put("code", code1);
            dtail.put("name", name1);
            dtail.put("code", code2);
            dtail.put("name", name2);
            dtail.put("code", code3);
            dtail.put("name", name3);

            Log.e("Result------", "" + dtail);

        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this time i am getting error like this index 1 out of range [0..1]

Comment: Json parsing is done for your posted json It works fine i have tested it.

Comment: app is completely builded but when i run app that time am getting error from run() method"json parsing error:index1 out of range[0..1]"

Comment: then posted Json is not the same Please check

Comment: No posted Jason is same as posted

Comment: E/Result------: {Train Number=17603, no=2, total passengers=2, Train Name=KCG YPR EXP, responseCode=200, day=20, Class=SL, chart=Y, error=false, code=KCG, coach_position=9, booking_status=S7,59,GN, year=2015, current_status=S7,59, month=8, dateofJoin=20-8-2015, name=KACHEGUDA, FAILURE_RATE=19.346153846153847, pnr=1234567890}

Comment: See the result what i get.

Comment: Can u post complete code I think I have got some other error

Comment: Can u give me your email so that I will send u whole code and you can make error free

Comment: This time I am getting error"value at train_num of type java.lang.String cannot converted to int

Comment: String train_num = object.getString("train_num"); use this

Comment: but train number is not in string so why shoild i?

Comment: I said as per log error that is the fix I have shown you results it works fine idk why it doesn't for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

Hope this will help you. Whenever you work with JSON check all key name. It should always same as response key name

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    HashMap<String, String> dtail = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("passengers");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int no = Integer.parseInt(o.optString("no").toString());
                        String booking_status = o.getString("booking_status");
                        String current_status = o.getString("current_status");
                        String coach_position = o.getString("coach_position");
                        dtail.put("no", String.valueOf(no));
                        dtail.put("Booking Staus", booking_status);
                        dtail.put("Current Staus", current_status);
                        dtail.put("Coach Positon", coach_position);
                    }

                        String train_name = object.getString("train_name");
                        int train_num = Integer.parseInt(object.optString("train_num").toString());
                        int pnr = Integer.parseInt(object.optString("pnr").toString());
                        String chart_prepared = object.getString("chart_prepared");
                        int total_passengers = Integer.parseInt(object.optString("total_passengers").toString());

                        JSONObject date = object.getJSONObject("train_start_date");
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(date.optString("month").toString());
                        int year = Integer.parseInt(date.optString("year").toString());
                        int day = Integer.parseInt(date.optString("day").toString());


                        JSONObject co = object.getJSONObject("from_station");
                        String code = co.getString("code");
                        String name = co.getString("name");

                        JSONObject co1 = object.getJSONObject("boarding_point");
                        String code1 = co1.getString("code");
                        String name1 = co1.getString("name");

                        JSONObject co2 = object.getJSONObject("to_station");
                        String code2 = co2.getString("code");
                        String name2 = co2.getString("name");

                        JSONObject co3 = object.getJSONObject("reservation_upto");
                        String code3 = co3.getString("code");
                        String name3 = co3.getString("name");



                        dtail.put("Train Name", train_name);
                        dtail.put("Train Number", String.valueOf(train_num));
                        dtail.put("pnr", String.valueOf(pnr));
                        dtail.put("chart prepared", chart_prepared);
                        dtail.put("total passengers", String.valueOf(total_passengers));
                        dtail.put("month", String.valueOf(month));
                        dtail.put("year", String.valueOf(year));
                        dtail.put("day", String.valueOf(day));
                        dtail.put("code", code);
                        dtail.put("name", name);
                        dtail.put("code", code1);
                        dtail.put("name", name1);
                        dtail.put("code", code2);
                        dtail.put("name", name2);
                        dtail.put("code", code3);
                        dtail.put("name", name3);


                        dataList.add(dtail);



                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Json", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
```